# Grunt Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'isAbsolute'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

This error shows up when running grunt with the responsive-images-extender plugin. This is my configuration:

```
responsive_images_extender: {
        target: {
           options: {
             sizes: [{
               selector: 'img',
               sizeList: [{
                   cond: 'min-width: 300px',
                   size: '50vw'
                 }, {
                   cond: 'min-width: 700px',
                   size: '70vw'
                 }, {
                   cond: 'default',
                   size: '100vw'
               }]
             }]
           },
           files: [{
             expand: true,
             src: ['**/*.{html,htm,php}'],
             cwd: 'src/',
             dest: 'dist/'
           }]
         }
      }
```

Even with the options completely blank, I get the same error. 
What causes this error? I feel like it could be a typo, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using an old version of NodeJS. That function is deprecated and updating NodeJS will solve the issue.